# Language switcher in PHP

Tags: php

I have made a site with classic php and mysql functions. I order to insert a language switcher, how can I change the language of site without duplicating site folder?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really depends on the structure of your site. Check out [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329650/am-i-breaking-any-php-good-practice-in-the-following-php-array-which-deals-with), the asker has chosen an approach that is pretty simple to implement.

Comment: Thank you pekka;
but ı have to make this in database

Comment: @Jasmine You could load the words into a dictionary array, or use Zend_Translate for example.

Comment: I want something like this but fetching from db
http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html

Comment: @Jasmine Seeing as you already have an existing structure, and not knowing where exactly you're stuck, it's hard to give you any pointers on what to do. As I said, there are solutions for this around like Zend_translate, you can take a look at it. Maybe you need a custom-made solution but for that you will have to provide more info in your question.

Comment: I have made very simple system:
MySQL tables: category and content 
in content : catId, id, title, abstract and body,
I want to translate site with adding title_en, and body_en . 
I have found an article that used pear:
http://devzone.zend.com/article/4469
But I am not authorized to used pear.
BTW, thanks pekka for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution: [Lang Switcher PHP+MySQL](http://veliovgroup.com/item.php?id=124)